# How check if a double number has zero after the point?

Tags: flutter

How to check if a `double` number has zero after the point; if it has, then convert it to an `int` number.

For example:

- if the number = 13.0 … convert to 13
- if the number = 144.0 … convert to 144

Comment: You can test if a `double` is exactly representable as an `int` with `number == number.toInt()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your number's variable

```
var number = 13.0
```

you can simply perform:

```
var newNumber;
if (number is int) {
   newNumber = number.toInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  double a=144.0;
  
  print(a..ceilToDouble()); //must ..
```

**Output**

144.0 -> 144

144.1 -> 144.1

Comment: `..ceilToDouble()` doesn't do anything since the cascade operator will discard the result.  You're doing the equivalent of just `print(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
double number = 144.0;
if (number % 1 == 0) {
  print("Number is integer");
} else {
  print("Number is double");
}
```